# Firebase chained database requests not working properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react to write a function that sends a message, and first it does a GET request to a database based on an input. After that result, it gets puts in a State (receiverName). Finally it does a post request to database with that state and some other info.

However, the problem arises once it has finished. It seems that everything is there except that one field receiverName from state. It's like state disappears for some reason and leaves field empty (" "). I tried console logging everything and both GET and POST requests seem to work fine except that one thing.

```
const [receiverName, setReceiverName] = useState('')
const sendMessage = async () => {
      try {
         await db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(receiver)
            .get()
            .then(doc => {
               const name = doc.data().firstName} ${doc.data().lastName
               setReceiverName(name)
            })
            .then(
               db
                  .collection('messages')
                  .doc(receiver)
                  .collection('senders')
                  .doc(currentUser.email)
                  .set({
                     senderEmail: currentUser.email,
                     senderName: currentUser.displayName,
                     senderPhoto: currentUser.photoURL,
                     receiverEmail: receiver,
                     receiverName: receiverName,
                  })
          catch(error){
                console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line where you assigning `name` look like this:

```
const name = '${doc.data().firstName} ${doc.data().lastName}'
```

Otherwise looks ok.